# UWP | TabView class not recognizable from IDE

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml, winui

for some reason the **XAML** source code (**see** **below**) is not discoverable by the **Integrated** **Development** **Environment** (**IDE**).

---

```
<Page
    x:Class="Network.Interface"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Network"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

     <Grid>

    <muxc:TabView>
        <muxc:TabView.TabItems>
            <muxc:TabViewItem />
        </muxc:TabView.TabItems>
    </muxc:TabView>

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

---

#### Notice

IDE - **JetBrains Rider 2021.1.2**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use *muxc:TabView* on xaml page correctly, please refer to the following steps.

1.Download the corresponding package through Package Manager.
Steps: **Reference**->**Manage NuGet Packages**->**Browse**->Search *Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls* and install it.

[image]

2.Add *xmlns:muxc="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls"* to page element, as follows:

```
<Page
...
xmlns:muxc="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
...
</Page>
```

Comment: The only package that is associated with the TabView class is: `Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls`